# Does it cause wear on a clutch if it's partially engaged, but in neutral?

Tags: clutch

Just wondering if it causes any wear engaging/disengaging the clutch if you're in neutral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't really cause any additional wear on the clutch itself, but you'll be taxing the throwout bearing. It gets worked every time you push the pedal down to disengage the clutch. When you are in neutral, you still cause wear on this part. Doubly so if you are holding the clutch at any point in the travel to the point where the clutch itself is anywhere from partially to fully disengaged.